# Suppress printed output from ExternalEvaluate

Tags: output, external-calls

`ExternalEvaluate` likes to print whatever hits stdout or stderr in the course of evaluation. For example,

```
In[1]= ExternalEvaluate["Shell", "echo 'hi!'"]
```

```
hi!
```

```
Out[1]= Success[...]
```

I'd like to suppress this printed output and just extract the stdout from the actual output. How can I do that?

I would have hoped there would be an analogue of e.g. `QuietEcho` or an option for `ExternalEvaluate` that controls this, but I couldn't find either.

I'm guessing it will involve finding a way to intercept `$Output` somehow?

Comment: Have you trie Block[{Print}, code]?

Comment: @JasonB. Oh, yup, that did it! I guess I didn't expect `Print` to be used internally!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ExternalEvaluate` will attempt to route any external print-like output directly to `Print`. To disable this you can just `Block` that symbol during evaluation:

```
In[2]:= Block[{Print},
 ExternalEvaluate["Shell", "echo 'hi!'"]
 ]

Out[2]= Success["ExecutionCompleted", <|...|>]
```